# Can a literary self-analysis question be made on-topic and not too broad/too localized?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

On my website I recently posted [some comments on some verse I wrote](https://sites.google.com/site/paulclaytonplace/verse-works/light_verse-html#TOC-Some-comments-on-these-works). Much of this content concerns how certain aspects enhance the communication of the meaning, but in hindsight I am wondering if these effects are primarily imagined, coming from my analytical mindset and cognitive biases from knowing the intended meaning.

A writer of verse can benefit from a true understanding of how form participates in the communication of sense, especially taken the writer's own works. This implies that questions on this topic *could* be on-topic here (and not require a literary criticism Stack Exchange—for which the questions would probably be off-topic because they concerned self-analysis of far from great works).

A general question such as "How can one discern whether supposed lyric effects are real or imagined?" might be too broad and "bad subjective" (excluding the practical answer of asking others what lyric effects they perceived) and not sufficiently focused on writing.

Questions asking whether the supposed effects for specific (short) writings are real would seem to be excessively localized. (While specific critique questions are allowed on Writers, they are borderline questions—tending toward being too localized—and the literary criticism orientation of supposed effects questions could easily push such questions over the border.)

This problem is made more difficult because the question I would *like* to ask is much more about literary criticism than writing. That is, the benefit would not be in improving the writing but about helping readers to more fully appreciate the writing (and potentially its weaknesses). That pushes it toward "what to write" rather than "how to write".

I already posted a [request for comments in a chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17140812#17140812) since I could not think of any way to make a decent Writers SE question. However, perhaps someone here can think of a way to make a useful (to Writers) question.

Comment: As usual, I am not sure if the proper tags have been used.